# How can i change the breadcrumbs in magento depending on the store selected

Tags: php, breadcrumbs, magento-1.7

I have build a website with 5 stores and i want the home link inside the breadcrumb to be as the store name.
ex: if i am in store 2 then i want the breadcrumb to be 2 > page title and not Home > page title.

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Static block .

Go to CMS->Static Blocks. Here you can create a static block with some name say custom_block.

Afterwards go to CMS->Widgets create a widget for each store with name say store1_widget1 and  set its visibility to the respective store. In that widget you can write content or can display images or any other stuff.

Call this static block named custom_block in the CMS.xml file in the head section and you are done.

This will help you out.